Is it possible to have the PCIE DMA to 2 different memory addresses for the same call?
Like the question asks, I am tasked to find a way to have the data coming off the PCIE bus into 2 memory regions. Normally I would just do a memcpy, but I was instructed this is not possible. I don't know why, it is just the requirement that was handed down to me so I was hoping that the PCIE bus could DMA into 2 addresses at the same time.

DMA copies from a device to a single address range, either physical or virtual depending on whether you are using an IOMMU. That destination could be a shared memory region so it can have multiple virtual addresses mappings from different processes.

I guess I should have specified, it needs to be 2 different physical addresses.

@stark DMA doesn't operate with physical addresses, it operates with bus addresses and depending on which bus you are considering (and on which side: src or dst) it might be the same as physical address in memory.
